React Native API Fetch - HTML Error & "Enable JavaScript" Message in Network Response
When I attempt the fetch, the network response contains an error message with HTML code.
The network preview displays the message "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
When I run the app on my physical Android device, the API fetch fails entirely, resulting in a network error.
I Have used this code to fetch api in react-native
package.json file code
i had set only proxy
{
  "name": "hypercodez",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "expo/AppEntry.js",
  "proxy":"https://hypercodez.rf.gd",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  {
   ...
  }
}

App.js file code to fetch data
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("/api.php", { method: 'GET' });
    console.log(response); // This line might be helpful for debugging
  };
  fetchData();
}, []);

This html code receiving in network response
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta httpEquiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <title>hypercodez</title>
    <!-- The `react-native-web` recommended style reset: https://necolas.github.io/react-native-web/docs/setup/#root-element -->
    <style id="expo-reset">
        /* These styles make the body full-height */
        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
        }

        /* These styles disable body scrolling if you are using <ScrollView> */
        body {
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        /* These styles make the root element full-height */
        #root {
            display: flex;
            height: 100%;
            flex: 1;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Use static rendering with Expo Router to support running without JavaScript. -->
    <noscript> You need to enable JavaScript to run this app. </noscript>
    <!-- The root element for your Expo app. -->
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=web&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.routerRoot=app" defer></script>
</body>

</html>


What are you expecting to happen?

I have created a simple api in php which returns {"messgae":"This is api response"} but when calling the api from react native, this data is not received and an html error code is received in the network response, which I have given in the above code.

Make sure your url for API is correct. Use absolute url not relative like "/api.php".

The url of the api is correct and when I tested the api with postman, I get the same errors in postman also.

So nothing to do with React Native then. I would guess that you are missing path from your url.
